# Как заставить реализацию абстрактного класса пометить конкретной аннотацией переопределяемое свойство?

Tags: java, android, компиляция, kotlin, аннотации

**Дано:**

Класс с абстрактным свойством.

**Задача:**

Заставить помечать это свойство определённой аннотацией в наследниках класса, инициализирующих сие свойство.

**Вопрос:**

Как таки это реализовать? И возможно ли это? Интересуют реализации на `Java` и `Kotlin`.

---

Класс выглядит так:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    /**
    * add @ThirdPartyLibraryAnnotation annotation in realization
    */
    abstract var myVar: MyType

}
```

И надо сделать так, чтобы `myVar` в наследнике обязательно помечали аннотацией так:

```
class MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass() {

    @ThirdPartyLibraryAnnotation
    override var myVar: MyType = MyType()

}
```

Comment: В общем оно решаемо. Через `annotationProcessing`. Позже напишу как в ответе.

Comment: Вот в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994338/how-to-get-annotations-of-interface-or-abstract-class-methods-in-java) дано решение, но необходим Spring.

Comment: @tizian, спасибо, но я давно нашёл как это сделать без него. Постараюсь в ближайшие дни раскопать код и в ответ написать)